# Elixir compilation error: module ExUnitProperties is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I upgraded the version of elixir from 1.7.4 to 1.15 and now I am trying to run `MIX_ENV=test mix test` and I keep getting an error `module ExUnitProperties is not loaded and could not be found` My mix.exs has `{:stream_data, "~> 0.1", only: :test, runtime: false}`. I've tried upgrading `stream_data` to the latest version but no avail.

Here's what I've tried already (MIX_ENV=test):

1. `mix deps.clean`
2. `mix compile --force`
3. `mix deps.tree` shows├── stream_data ~> 0.1 (Hex package)

mix.exs has:

```
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support", "test/fixtures"]
```

The full error is:

```
error: module ExUnitProperties is not loaded and could not be found. This may be happening because the module you are trying to load directly or indirectly depends on the current module
  test/support/generators.ex:4: Ab.Generators (module)
```

generators.ex is:

```
defmodule Ab.Generators do
  @moduledoc "Generators to use for property testing"

  use ExUnitProperties
  alias Ab.SafeTimex

  def datetime do
    ExUnitProperties.gen all(
                           year <- StreamData.member_of(1990..2030),
                           month <- StreamData.member_of(1..12),
                           day <- StreamData.member_of(1..31),
                           hour <- StreamData.member_of(0..23),
                           minute <- StreamData.member_of(0..59),
                           second <- StreamData.member_of(0..59)
                         ) do
      NaiveDateTime.new(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
    end
    |> StreamData.filter(&match?({:ok, _}, &1))
    |> StreamData.map(&elem(&1, 1))
    |> StreamData.map(&SafeTimex.to_datetime(&1, :utc))
  end
end
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Does the error change if you use `{:stream_data, "~> 0.1"}` in your `mix.exs` instead?

Comment: @Everett nope :(

Comment: Have you tried a full `rm -rf _build deps`?

Comment: How about the current version? `{:stream_data, "~> 0.6.0"}`?

Comment: @Everett Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I fixed the issue by adding `stream_data` to the `application` struct in `mix.exs` now I need to research what that did :) The weird part is prior to upgrading to 1.15 it doesn't seem like that was necessary.

Comment: Actually getting rid of the application struct entirely worked too. I think it's because of this:

Output of `mix help compile.app`:

```:applications - all applications your application depends on at
    runtime. By default, this list is automatically inferred from your
    dependencies. Mix and other tools use the application list in order to
    start your dependencies before starting the application itself.```